# Play Framework 2

Tags: playframework, url-routing, httprequest

I have a question concerning best practices: What is the best way of handling GET and POST requests within an application? Should it be done using two separate controller methods (one for POST and one for GET) or handled together in one. Are their any advantages/disadvantages to either option? Both are feasible and work, I would just like to hear from the community on their opinions. I am using the play framework however this could apply to any MVC framework really. Below I have created a simple example of the second option just for reference.

In the routes file there are two routes defined (ensuring POST is above GET so that it takes precedence) both pointing to the same method:

```
POST  /index           controllers.Application.index()
GET   /index           controllers.Application.index()
```

In the Application controller we have one method:

```
public static Result index() {
    if (request().method().equals("POST")) {
       // bind, validate, return badRequest if hasErrors else capture and redirect
    }        
    return Results.ok(index.render("Home", Application.testForm));
}
```

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to use [Rails-style routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions), which makes the routes file look like

```
GET    /foos          controllers.FooController.index()
GET    /foos/new      controllers.FooController.new_form()
POST   /foos          controllers.FooController.create()
GET    /foos/:id      controllers.FooController.show(id:Long)
GET    /foos/:id/edit controllers.FooController.edit_form()
PUT    /foos/:id      controllers.FooController.update(id:Long)
DELETE /foos/:id      controllers.FooController.delete(id:Long)
```

This keeps most of the code that deals with Foo objects in the same place, with any utility methods closeby.  You can probably make a smarter Play router that sets up these routes automatically, like Rails' resources.

Comment: Hehe, you were first +1 ;)

Comment: Thanks, your comments (and biesior as well) have changed my way of looking at controllers! appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Usually `GET` and `POST` does quite other things therefore it will be more comfortable for you if you'll do it with typical REST approach

```
GET     /objects/:id       controllers.Application.objFindSingle(id: Int)
GET     /objects           controllers.Application.objFindAll
PUT     /objects/:id       controllers.Application.objUpdate(id: Int)
POST    /objects           controllers.Application.objCreate
DELETE  /objects/:id       controllers.Application.objDelete(id: Int)
```